# FirstOrDefault "Faking" Database

Tags: c#, asp.net

As i said i got a NullReference Issue, where an record is already in database but the method (cannot access it?) and returns null.

I am using EntityFramework, CodeFirst approach.

My Class FunctionPersonnels

```
public class FonctionPersonnel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public String Nom { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public float Cote { get; set; }

}
```

My BddContext:

```
public class BddContext1 : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Input> Inputs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<FonctionPersonnel> FonctionsPersonnels { get; set; }
}
```

My Dal:

```
    private readonly BddContext1 bdd;

    public Dal()
    {
        bdd = new BddContext1();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        bdd.Dispose();
    }
    public float ObtenirCoeficient(int id)
    {
        var inputTrouve = bdd.Inputs.FirstOrDefault(input => input.Id == id); // Accessing the row that would be edited
        String fonctionName = inputTrouve.Fonction; // fonctionName == "RESPONSABLE RESERVE"
        var fonctionCote = bdd.FonctionsPersonnels.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Nom == fonctionName); // fonctionCote == null
        return fonctionCote.Cote;
    }
```

The FonctionPersonnel dump:
[FonctionPersonnel database's dump](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTbGb.png)

Here RESPONSABLE RESERVE exist in database and got a Cote, but the method FirstOrDefault() return null...

Why it returns null, while RESPONSABLE RESERVE already exist in FonctionsPersonnels ?

I resolve the problem momentary by adding the functionName with its cote again in the database, but now i got a duplicated FonctionPersonnel entries, this is not working for me.

PS: I just downloaded Microsoft SQL Manager Studio, and launched a SQL Server Profiler , the track file :
https://files.fm/u/hjry7684

Check The Track:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP (1) 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[Nom] AS [Nom], 
[Extent1].[Cote] AS [Cote]
FROM [dbo].[FonctionPersonnels] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[Nom] = @p__linq__0',N'@p__linq__0 nvarchar(4000)',@p__linq__0=N'CAISSIER'
```

Comment: Hi, what is your question?

Comment: Why do you not use DependencyInjection to access the database context in the service / controller?

Comment: @Reniuz My Question is Why The firstordefault() method returns null, while RESPONSABLE RESERVE already exist in FonctionsPersonnels ?

Comment: @DTeuchert I'm not experienced enough could you share with me some information about it ?

Comment: Forget the dependency injection - that's got nothing to do with your issue - let's fix that first then look at DI.  If you are using CodeFirst, what type of DB initializer are you using?  Is it possible that the database is getting redeployed each time?  What method are you using to verify that the record does in fact exist in the database?  Are you sure that method and when the above code runs you are connecting to the same database?

Comment: Simplified: In the Sartup.cs you configure the framework service and then you can access the DbContext from the controller or service in the constructor `public Dal(BddContext1 context){...}` Have a look on [EF Core on ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/new-db?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

Comment: That's because something is wrong. That means your `p.Nom` is not equal to what you think. And we have no idea why. Dump the actual `p.Nom` value and dump the value of `fonctionName` compare both of them side by side.

Comment: @Brendan Green So i got no DB initializer, should i use one ? how could i check if it is redeployed each time ? I did not define any method to verify it, it's my first attempt. I guess yes, because it works fine when i duplicated it . The clue is When i added the RESPONSABLE RESERVE it worked just fine, but i can't find the source of the problem

Comment: @DTeuchert Humm, i'm taking a look, but this is not the problem though.

Comment: @Reniuz I already did, look at the comments on the code.

Comment: You didn't dump what is inside of `bdd.FonctionsPersonnels`

Comment: I'm adding the dump

Answer (score 2):

If you have a record in the FonctionsPersonnels table with the exact string value that `inputTrouve.Fonction` is returning when you query the database, I don't see why it would return null. You may want to carefully debug this, checking database records at runtime and watching queries against the database using the **SQL Server Profiler**, as the record you're querying might be getting modified by something else. I will also suggest reimplementing that method with the `using` keyword:

```
public float ObtenirCoeficient(int id)
{
    using (var context = new BddContext1())
    {
        var fonctionName = context.Inputs.FirstOrDefault(input => input.Id == id)?.Fonction;
        return context.FonctionsPersonnels.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Nom == fonctionName).Cote;
    }
}
```

Comment: How could i use the SQL Server Profiler please ?

Comment: Via the Tools menu of SQL Server Management Studio, or by finding the executable within the SQL Server Tools installation folder, assuming you have those installed.

Comment: i downloaded the SQL Server MAnagmeent Studio, and runned a SQL Server Profiler, and got this (i'll add it to the post)

Comment: The fonctionName variable is apparently the problem, your code is querying the database for FonctionPersonnel.Nom = 'CAISSIER', and not "RESPONSABLE RESERVE" as you wrote on your comment, and that's probably why you are getting null. Check the ID you are passing to the method to make sure you're pulling the right records.

Answer (score 1):

By adding a debug statement like below to your DataContext class constructor you can view the actual sql executed in the Debug window. Paste that into SQL server and see why you are getting 0 rows.

```
    Database.Log = delegate (string str) { Debug.WriteLine(str); };
```

Usually this is only used in Debug, remove for production deployments or wrap in a conditional to only run when in Debug

Comment: @loug-eagle According to your trace you are looking for a FonctionPersonnels avec Nom = 'CAISSIER'. From the Table Image you do not have any with that Nom

Comment: Could you please clarify more ? I just started working with The SQL Server Profiler. What is a Table Image? And wich event are you looking at (in the trace file)?

Comment: Just the image of the table data you linked to this question, and the one query that you added to your question.

Comment: You should be able to paste the queries from Profiler or logging (as I described above) into Sql Server Management Studio and see the same results that entity framework returns.